# Redundant polygons created from ArcMap to Illustrator

Tags: polygon, adobe-illustrator, arcmap

I created a polygon layer whose part of it was generated from buffers based on a feature line layer (200m around lines). So when the map scale is small (zoom out), this polygon layer still looks like a feature line layer but it is actually not.
   The problem occurred when this polygon layer was exported from ArcMap to Illustrator (save as AI format, already set vectorized). Once I opened the AI file, Illustrator always automatically created redundant polygons in the areas that were closed by multiple line segments. How can I solve this issue?

Correct/ original polygon shapes in ArcMap:

[image: correct pattern]

Incorrect shapes with redundant polygons in Illustrator:

[image: incorrect pattern]

Comment: Many packages that export to illustrator confuse fill and stroke. Looks like you have open shapes in Illustrator with a fill. Try selecting them and using "none" as the fill colour, leaving only the stroke.

Comment: if a layer has multiple polygon objects with different classified colors, how can I switch their colors from fill to stroke at one time?

Comment: Your best to select them one colour at a time (select one then `select -> same fill`)